# Stuck with a simple issue on SQL Query on Microsoft Access that I can't figure out, showing both empty and filled fields

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have two tables, one of them listing Game Titles, and the other listing the Date it was purchased. I need the Query to still show games that were not purchased with an empty field, while listing the game in the next column.

Current Code:

```
SELECT Game.Title, GameOrder.[Date Purchased]
FROM Game INNER JOIN GameOrder ON Game.[Game ID] = GameOrder.[Game ID]
ORDER By [Date Purchased] ASC;
```

Tried looking online everywhere and I can't seem to find a solution for it, would really appreciate some help on this one thing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your image, if you want to show null fields for values that are not present in GameOrder, you need a Left Outer Join and not an INNER JOIN like you've used.

Comment: Woo! That was it thanks! Sorry if it was really simple and dumb, I usuall always get stuck on the simple things :p Thanks!